# Using $scope.$on in component constructor or in $onInit function?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Where is the best place in a component to register a scope event listener? Is it in the constructor or in the $onInit function?

Is it ok to do it in the constructor? The advantage of doing it in the constructor is that I may not need to create a private field for the $scope in the component, but I am unsure if its OK since the component is not fully initialized yet.

This

```js
public constructor($scope: ng.IScope) {
    $scope.$on("myCustomEvent", (_event, args) => {
        ...
    });
}
```

Or this:

```js
public constructor(private readonly $scope: ng.IScope) {
}

public $onInit() {
    this.$scope.$on("myCustomEvent", (_event, args) => {
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: The scope event bus is obsolete. It is best to avoid it. If you must use it, there is no harm in putting a listener in the constructor.